# How to log messages which have failed to acknowledged in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am reading messages from Kafka and processing them in storm.

I can see some messages which are failing in Storm UI.

I want to log these messages and figure out why these messages failed. There are no messages in logs as such for this.

Comment: Try to enable debugging via `Config.setDebug(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

If they have failed then they are supposed to be replayed by the Spout again. The `KafkaSpout` should have a `fail` method which you can use to identify the failed `messageId`s.

This might provide some direction.

Answer (score -1):

The logs of every topology execution are stored in the logs folder (apache-storm-0.10.0/logs).